# Cannot connect View Controller to Swift file

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I created a second view controller in the storyboard. I also created a new Swift-file with `File - New - Cocoa....`. Now I want to associate that Swift-file with the second view controller. So I highlight the second view controller, and click `Show Identity Inspector`. In `Custom Class` in the `Class` field I normally would add the Swift-file in order to create i.e. outlets. However, I cannot find the newly created Swift-file in there.

Thats the code from the new Swift-file

```
import UIKit

    class EditImageViewController: NSObject {

}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Show your code in new controller and check its module is your App Name

Comment: @Scriptable added the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your newly created Swift file. You need to declare a class which inherits from UIViewController.

Like:

```
class SomeViewController: UIViewController {

}
```

Then you will be able to connect IBOutlets and IBActions to this class.

If you are still having issues after your class inherits from UIViewController check the file inspector and ensure that the {your app name} target is checked (so that the file belongs to the correct module)